# Smallest prime factor of this $40$ million digit number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, fermat-numbers

Concatenate the Fermat numbers $F_0=2^{2^0}+1$ to $F_{26}=2^{2^{26}}+1$ in base $10$.

This gives $$3517257655374294967297\cdots9215379822913519617$$ a huge number with $$40\ 403\ 579$$ digits. Because of its size it is extremely likely that it is composite. Were it prime , it would be a new record prime number.

But what is its smallest prime factor ? According to my search , there is no prime factor below $2\cdot 10^9$. Can we do anything better than trial division despite the enormous size of the given number ? Maybe , ECM ?

Comment: A bit of experimentation with random integers with $20$ digits gives several numbers with its smallest prime factor with $8$ or $9$ digits. Several random integers with $30$ digits with smallest prime factor with $12$ digits or more. Several random integers with $40$ digits with smallest prime factor with $17$ digits or more. With a little of bad luck it could be that the smallest prime factor of the number you're considering to be of millions of digits, completely out of range of the current methods of factoring.

Comment: @jjagmath The smallest prime factor can be huge , but that it has millions of digits is very unlikely , of course not impossible.

Comment: @jjagmath A huge random number has no prime factor below $10^n$ with probability $1:(4.1\cdot n)$. If the smallest prime factor has , say $100$ digits , we are however already screwed , but I hope that we are lucky.

Comment: Can you compute $2^{n-1} \bmod n$?

Comment: @Peder I cannot follow this argument. We do not have the $26$ th Fermat number. How do you conclude that the factors must have the claimed form ?

Comment: @martycohen This would take an eternity with the tools I have available.

Comment: I have extended the search to include all primes below $7.15 \cdot 10^{10}$, i.e. none divide your concatenation.

Comment: @jorisperrenet I arrived only at $14\cdot 10^9$. This number is apparently tough.